# android: is it possible to read what activity aliases are set in the manifest?

Tags: android, android-activity, alias

I know that a bunch of data that is set in the manifest can be read via the [Package Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html). Is there a convenient way to do something similar for [`activity-alias`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element.html) data? If there is no convenient way, is it even possible?

Comment: I dont think you should need to do that. Why do you what to read the Activity Alias?

Comment: I'm writing an SDK and would like to be able to check if the user included an optional activity alias that we asked them to. Specifically [this case](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41381).